# VEmap is not defined in firefox

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, bing-maps

I'm using Bing maps in my code, url which I'm using is https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations/

In loadMap() function I'm intializing object to VEMap. It is working fine in IE and Chrome but in Firefox it is giving **"VEmap is not defined"** error. What would be the possible issue. How do I resolve it?.

Div block

```
<div id='map' style="position: relative; height: 240px;z-index:0;">
```

My code

```
function loadMap()
{ 
map = new VEMap('map');
mapCenter= new VELatLong(51.8756, -97.9956)
}
```

Comment: Check if you're setting the charset to utf-8 in the meta of the page. 
You should paste your code in pasteit or anything so we can have a look at the whole HTML page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use version 6.3 of Bing Maps. If this is a new development project use version 7 of Bing Maps, version 6.3 is nearing end of life (already announced).

As for your issue, it's likely a timing issue, or an incorrect script reference. For your current code you should have a script reference in the head of your page like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3"></script>
```

If you don't have this then this is likely your issue. If you have this at the bottom of your page then its likely the loadMap function is being called before the map script is loaded. You can do a couple different things to handle this. One is to ensure the map script is loade dby checking in your loadmap function that VEMap is defined and if it isn't then waiting for a bit then try loading the map again, like this:

```
function loadMap()
{ 
    if(typeof(VEMap) === 'undefined'){
        setTimeout(loadMap, 150);
        return;
    }

    map = new VEMap('map');
    map.SetCredentials("BingMapsKey"); 
    mapCenter= new VELatLong(51.8756, -97.9956)
}
```

All that said, you should be using v7 of Bing Maps as it's much faster, has more features, is the main map control used by people developing with Bing Maps, and is not nearing end of life. If you have a big app you need to migrate to v7 you can find a guide here: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/20958.migrating-bing-maps-v6-3-to-v7.aspx#Loading_a_Map

Alternatively, you can find documentation and resources for V7 here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg427610.aspx

https://www.bingmapsportal.com/ISDK/AjaxV7

https://bingmapsv7modules.codeplex.com/

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rbrundritt/archive/2014/09/04/the-art-of-intellisense-three-ways-to-use-intellisense-with-bing-maps-apis.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your generous solution. Bing URL(V6.3 ) I have used is "https://ecn.dev.virtualearth.net/mapcontrol/mapcontrol.ashx?v=6.3&s=1&mkt=fr-fr&onScriptLoad=initMap". It is working fine in IE, chrome and other browsers but Firefox. I have modified https to http and removed query string 's=1' (SSL) from URL then it started working in Firefox (working fine in IE, chrome and others also). I would like to know what is causing problem with Firefox in this regard. TY.